# Can I install SharePoint Designer 2010 on a machine that has Office 2007 installed?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My desktop at work has Office 2007 installed (but not SPD2007). Is it possible to install SPD2010? If so, which version (x86 or x64)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. I would install same bits as your current office installation.

See this page for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739063/sharepoint-designer-for-sp2010